# Hide Div based on height of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to hide a div when the height of my iframe reaches a certain size without the page needed to be reloaded

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if ($(".remove-text").height() <= 582) {
        $("#execphp-31").hide();
    } else {
        $("#execphp-31").show();
    };
});
</script>
```

This works on page load but if the iframe size changes it doesn't update the show/hide function

Comment: Run this logic in under the `resize()` event of the `window`. Also note that it would be better to do this in CSS using media queries instead of JS

Comment: dont think it is possible in css media queries as when the height of one div exceeds a certain value i want to hide a completely different div?

Comment: Ah yes. CSS would only worked based on window size.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling it on both window load and window resize.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  if ($(".remove-text").height() <= 582) {
    $("#execphp-31").hide();
  } else {
    $("#execphp-31").show();
  };
});
```

Comment: Note that you'll also have to check on page load in your scenario.

Comment: @zoubida13 I thought it will be obvious, but thank you anyway, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the this code to both the window load and resize events.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).bind("load resize", function() {
        if ($(".remove-text").height() <= 582) {
            $("#execphp-31").hide();
        } else {
            $("#execphp-31").show();
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: on page load div is hidden but on re-size div doesn't re-appear

Comment: Just FYI `bind()` is deprecated. Use `on()` instead

Comment: @iTsHutchy  Hmm.. is the height of .remove-text greater than 582 during page load?

Comment: is there a way to do this without .resize and the window dosent re-size the iframe just increases in height so it wont recognise until a re-size is made

Comment: So please clarify.  What events change the height of the iframe?  Identify those events and bind them to your if logic for showing and hiding the div.

Comment: @user9263373 I use a iframe-resize script which re-sizes the iframe based on its content therefore when its content gets over a certain size i.e 582px i want to hide a div as it takes up too much content on page

Comment: Ok perfect, so place your conditional logic in the iframe-resize function.

Comment: @user9263373  this is the script <script type="text/javascript" defer>
jQuery('iframe').load(function(){ setTimeout(function(){ 
iFrameResize({
//log: true, // Enable console logging
checkOrigin:false,
enablePublicMethods: true,
});
//alert('test');
},2500);
});
</script>

Comment: is `iFrameResize()` a function you coded or is it a plugin you're calling?  If it's your own function, then put the conditional logic in there.